# Validate email (without sending confirmation)

Tags: java, regex, validation, email-validation

## Validation emails aren't an option :(

I have a very specific set of rules that I need to use to validate email addresses.  I've tried the Apache Commons library as well as the JavaMail library; although both of those adhere to RFC 2822, some emails that are invalid according to my rules get through.  I have been trying my luck with regexes (regexi?) to no avail.  I know, I know.  A regex isn't the best option and can take a lot of time and add complications.  Still, I figured since I have rules outlined in not so difficult terms that building one for this specific instance will suffice.

#### The Rules:

1. Local part of email address may use any of:

   - Upper- and lowercase letters
   - Digits 0-9
   - Special characters: , ! # $ % ^ & * ( ) ' ` + = - _ { } | ~
   - A period, but cannot start or end with a period
   - May not contain successive periods
2. There must be an At Symbol (@) between the local and domain portions of email
3. Domain must contain only letters, digits, underscores, periods and hyphens

   - Cannot begin with a hyphen
   - Cannot end with a hyphen
   - Cannot contain two successive hyphens
4. There must be a period between the domain and TLD portions of the email

   - TLD must only contain letters
   - TLD must not end with a period

So far I have been trying to use the following regex:

<del>^((?!.\.{2,}.)[^.][-a-zA-Z0-9_.\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\,\'\+\=\`\{\|\}\~\-]+[^.])@((?!.\-{2,}.)[^-_][-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+[^-_]\.[a-zA-z]+)$</del>

```
^((?!.\.{2,}.)[^.][-a-zA-Z0-9_.!@#$%^&*(),'+=`{|}~-]+[^.])@((?!.\-{2,}.)[^-_][-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+[^-_]\.[a-zA-z]+)$
```

This is still failing with invalid emails (e.g. justlikethat@gm--ail.com).

What am I missing or doing wrong with the regex?  Is there another way I can ensure an email conforms to the requirements without a regex?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. This is in Java, so all escaped characters in above regex have to be double escaped (e.g. `\.` is `\\.`).  I have also been using [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com) to help me visualize this since I am obviously no regex guru.

Comment: That's an endless and vain quest. Read [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Your Complex Regex](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Comment: I know, unfortunately my client doesn't agree.

Comment: Change clients .... seriously.

Comment: My eyes hurt from starring at this regex in Rublar.com and then coming back to this page to see if any comments/progress have been made.  It is mui complex!

Comment: Imagine how I feel...

Comment: If you are faced with a problem that you choose to solve with a regular expression, you are now faced with two problems :) Seriously, even if you manage to get a regex that satisfies the requirement, what are the chances that you'd ever be able to understand it in the future if the requirement changes?

Comment: Is it possible for you to go thru your list of requirements and see which ones are satisfied by the standard validation routines in the Apache / JavaMail libraries and which are not? You could then use the libraries to weed out most of the problems in the addresses and just have to apply a smaller subset of your rules to the ones that pass your validation. Any mileage in that?

Comment: This is what I've been trying to explain to them.  Also, the world will end if they send out a confirmation email.  I'm dealing with Stannis, not Robert.  And there's no justice.

Comment: I've been thinking about splitting the String at the '@' and validating each element in the returned Array by itself.  Splitting the domain and TLD would be trickier with that.  I don't think I can `split` starting from the end of the Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common wisdom is that e-mails are too complex for single regex. It is easier to check an e-mail address by seeing if an SMTP server can send it. You have already been told that.

So, assuming you need to pre-validate an address (and assuming it is only the email portion, and not all the goodies you can have like unicode names, etc.) then my recommendation would be:

1. Break the problem down in to smaller parts
2. Give each part a method
3. Validate each part (perhaps in a loop).
4. Use combination of regex and standard logic to make sure it is valid (according to your rules)

This is the only realistic way to leave a somewhat reasonable system that's maintainable and understandable by the poor sucker who sees the code next time.

e.g.

```
private void validateNamePart(String npart) {
  if (!npart.matches("")) {
    throw new .....;
  }
}

private void validateName(String name) {
  int parts = 0;
  for (String npart : name.split("\\.")) {
    validateNamePart(npart);
    parts++;
  }
  if (parts == 0) {
     throw ....;
  }
}

private void validateDomainPart(String dpart) {
  ....
}

private void validateDomain(String domain) {
  ....
}

public void validateEMail(String email) {
  String parts = email.split("@");
  if (parts.length == 2) {
    validateName(parts[0]);
    validateDomain(parts[1]);
  } else {
    throw ....
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up splitting the email String at the `@` and the last `.`, then testing each part of the email against a simple regex for each rule.  Thanks for the time and effort you gave to helping me!

Comment: In my opinion, having each function return `boolean` rather than throwing exceptions would be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

**I suggest:**

Split on the `@` symbol. Split on the last period (using [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and [`String#lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29)). Now you have the local part, the domain and the TLD all in separate strings, use if-statements to validate. If there are any rules applicable to all (2 consecutive periods?), do that before splitting. Much simpler to get right, much simpler to understand, much simpler to maintain.

**But, if you really want to stick to regex, here's a few things I've seen:**

The `[^.]` before the `@` should be `(?<!\.)`, otherwise the last character before the `@` can be just about anything.

`.` is **just one character**, so `(?!.\-{2,}.)` and `(?!.\.{2,}.)` does not do what you think it does. Just making it `.*` seems to fix it. And you don't need to check any characters after the things you're looking for.

It hasn't been explicitly stated, but I presume the domain and TLD can't contain 2 successive periods either. If this is allowed, the first part of the regex needs to be `(?!.*\.{2,}.*@)` to stop at the `@`.

If you use [`String#matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), the `^` and `$` isn't required.

There's some unneeded `()`'s.

Final regex:

```
(?!.*\.{2,})[^.][-a-zA-Z0-9_.!@#$%^&*(),'+=`{|}~-]+(?<!\.)@(?!.*\-{2,})[^-_][-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+[^-_]\.[a-zA-z]+
```

If you choose to stick to regex, I suggest extensive commenting:

```java
String regex =
          "(?!.*\\.{2,})" // doesn't contain 2 consecutive .'s
       // local part
          + "[^.]" // doesn't start with a .
          + "[-a-zA-Z0-9_.!@#$%^&*(),'+=`{|}~-]+" // valid chars for local part
          + "(?<!\\.)" // last char of local part isn't a .
       // at symbol
          + "@"
       // domain
          ...
```

It might seem like overkill, but you'll wish you had if you try to maintain it a few months down the line, especially if you haven't touched any regex in those months.

Comment: Gahhh I feel bad not choosing your answer since you took time to put this regex together for me!  I ended up splitting the email at the `@` and the last `.`, then just tested each email part against a simple regex for each rule.  Thank you so much for your time and effort helping me!